# Null is not a subType of String in my flutter newsapp

Tags: flutter

Am working on a newsapp using the newsapi.org to fetch data from the list of articles but it returns an exception of null is not a sub type of String in the Article.fromJson and i would like to ask for some help.Thank you

```
//this is my Article class


import 'package:news_app/source_models.dart';
class Article{
  Source source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? content;

  Article({required this.source,required this.author,required this.title,required this.description,required this.url,
    required this.content});

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json){
    return Article(
      source: Source.fromJson(json['source']),
      author: json['author']as String,
      title: json['title'] !=null?json['title'].toString():'',
      description: json['description']as String,
      url: json['url']as String,
      content: json['content']as String,
    );
  }
  Map<String,dynamic>ToJson(Article article)=><String,dynamic>
  {
    "source":article.source,
    "author":article.author,
    "title":article.title,
    "description":article.description,
    "url":article.url,
    "content":article.content,


  };
}


//this is the api


import 'package:news_app/Article.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class ApiService{
  static Future<List<Article>>article()async{
    List<Article>?articles;
    final http.Response response=await http.get(Uri.parse('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=eac151759e98448f8712913e2028cfd0'));
if(response.statusCode==200){
  Map<String,dynamic>json=jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<dynamic>body=json['articles'];
  articles=body.map((item) => Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
}

 return articles!;
  }
}



//this is the source class

class Source{

  String name;

  Source({required this.name});

  factory Source.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json){
    return Source(

        name:json['name']);
  }
  Map<String,dynamic>ToJson(Source sources){
    return <String,dynamic>{

      "name":sources.name,
    };
  }
}
```

//this is my UI

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news_app/ApiService.dart';
import 'package:news_app/Article.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  createState()=>_HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen>{
 bool isWaiting=false;
  List<Article>articles=[];
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    IncomingApi();
  }

  void IncomingApi()async{
    isWaiting=true;
    var data=await ApiService.article();
    setState(() {
      articles=data;
      isWaiting=false;
    });
}
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body:ListView.builder(
          itemCount: articles.length,
          itemBuilder:(context, index) {
            NewsContainer(context, articles[index]);
            return Center(
                child:CircularProgressIndicator()
                    );
          }) );

  }
  Widget NewsContainer(BuildContext context,Article article){
    return Container(
      child:ListTile(
        title:Text(article.description!) ,
      )
    );
  }

}
```

//I made checks on all the fields but didnt work,i also tried using the futureBuilder and nothing comes out of it and i certainly dont clearly understand why the Source.fromJson didnt produce any exception if truely nothing is being passed on to the Article.fromJson.And please all answers will be appreciated.

Comment: In your model any key response is null check one time it's type is string but you getting null value instead of string. Also add uncaught exception debug point to get exact error area

Comment: So please with your first statement what should i do

Answer (score 3):

As some of the inputs are `null`, you should cast `String` with nullable operator `?`.

```
class Article{
  Source source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? content;

  Article({required this.source,required this.author,required this.title,required this.description,required this.url,
    required this.content});

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json){
    return Article(
      source: Source.fromJson(json['source']),
      author: json['author']as String?,
      title: json['title'] !=null?json['title'].toString():'',
      description: json['description']as String?,
      url: json['url']as String?,
      content: json['content']as String?,
    );
  }
  Map<String,dynamic>ToJson()=><String,dynamic>
  {
    "source": source,
    "author": author,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "url": url,
    "content": content,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code author string key value is null so app is crashing so here you need to add null-safety. so you need to user `??` operator instead of `!`.

also you can generate model from API response checkout this [link](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Also fixed few warnings in your code.

**Prefere bellow code.**

**Replace your Model classes**

```
class ArticleResponse {
  String? status;
  int? totalResults;
  List<Articles>? articles;

  ArticleResponse({this.status, this.totalResults, this.articles});

  ArticleResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    totalResults = json['totalResults'];
    if (json['articles'] != null) {
      articles = <Articles>[];
      json['articles'].forEach((v) {
        articles!.add(Articles.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['totalResults'] = totalResults;
    if (articles != null) {
      data['articles'] = articles!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Articles {
  Source? source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? content;

  Articles(
      {this.source,
      this.author,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.url,
      this.urlToImage,
      this.publishedAt,
      this.content});

  Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    source = json['source'] != null ? Source.fromJson(json['source']) : null;
    author = json['author'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    url = json['url'];
    urlToImage = json['urlToImage'];
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'];
    content = json['content'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (source != null) {
      data['source'] = source!.toJson();
    }
    data['author'] = author;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['url'] = url;
    data['urlToImage'] = urlToImage;
    data['publishedAt'] = publishedAt;
    data['content'] = content;
    return data;
  }
}

class Source {
  String? id;
  String? name;

  Source({this.id, this.name});

  Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

API Call service minor changes to map json in model.

```
class ApiService {
  static Future<List<Articles>> article() async {
    List<Articles>? articles;
    final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=eac151759e98448f8712913e2028cfd0'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body); 
      final fetchData = ArticleResponse.fromJson(json); // just need to add json response to map model 
      articles = fetchData.articles ?? []; // get article array from response.
      
    }

    return articles!;
  }
}
```

Home screen  widget

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  createState() => _HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool isWaiting = false;
  List<Articles> articles = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    incomingApi();
  }

  Future<void> incomingApi() async {
    isWaiting = true;
    List<Articles> data = await ApiService.article();
    setState(() {
      articles = data;
      isWaiting = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: isWaiting
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: articles.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return newsContainer(context, articles[index]);
              }),
    );
  }

  Widget newsContainer(BuildContext context, Articles article) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(article.description ?? ''),
    );
  }
}
```